# Converting djvu file into pdf file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I have different  DjVu files and I want to convert these files into pdf format.I am making an iPad  application in which I want to add this feature.How it can be achieved.My DjVu files are working fine in my application.

Comment: One option is as you might be rendering DjVu file in your App so capture snapshot of each page and create PDF.